# Transparent background goes black in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to create a window with rounded corner. I set Window background to transparent and set the border background to white. However on the region between the border and the window, I get black background instead of transparent.

I develop on C# WPF, VS2010 on Window 7. Below is my XAML and Screenshot.

**XAML:**

```
<Window WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="25" Background="White">
        <Grid>
            ... some content ...
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You also need to set `AllowsTransparency="True"` on your `Window` tag to use a Transparent Window Background

```
<Window WindowStyle="None" 
        Background="Transparent" 
        AllowsTransparency="True">

</Window>
```

Comment: @KMC That property is required to make WPF turn on Transparency and see whatever is behind the application. I know it works on XP and Windows 7. I haven't tested on Vista, but I would assume the same.