# How to have invisible form with visible buttons

Tags: wpf

I want to have buttons to be always be visible while the form itself is not;

meaning, I could click my desktop icons, for example, through the gap between wpf buttons?

any direction is appreciated, thanks

Comment: The answer here shows the basics of what you need : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8095043/302677 - I'm too lazy to copy/paste it to an answer though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Window`s Properties, enable AllowTransparency and set the background of the window to be Transparent and `WindowStyle` to `None` :)

Comment: You should be new to WPF :) Thats nothing :)